# Raspberry Pi java button pressed program showing 2 button pushes for some pushes

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am making a basic java program for the raspberry pi that prints, when a button is pressed, the button number and that its pressed. my 2 code classes are below but as you can see from the output, sometimes it shows the button is pressed twice for one push.

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalInput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.Pin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinPullResistance;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListenerDigital;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent;


public class Button {
private GpioPinDigitalInput buttonPin;
boolean pressed = false;


public Button(GpioController gpio, Pin pin) {
    // Provision the pin
    buttonPin = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(pin, PinPullResistance.PULL_UP);

    // Add a listener to the button
    buttonPin.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {

            if(event.getState().isLow()) {
                pressed = true;
                // When Button is not pressed
                GPIOTest.print(event.getPin() + ", pressed");

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

class 2

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
 import com.pi4j.io.gpio.Pin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.util.Console;

public class GPIOTest {
private final static Console console = new Console();
private final static GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

private static Pin[] pinList = { RaspiPin.GPIO_00,
                                RaspiPin.GPIO_01,
                                RaspiPin.GPIO_02,
                                RaspiPin.GPIO_03,
                                RaspiPin.GPIO_04};

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    console.title("Test GPIO");
    console.promptForExit();

    for (Pin pin : pinList) {
        new Button(gpio, pin);
    }

    console.waitForExit();
}

public static void print(String message) {
    console.println(message);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Likely to be a debounce issue.  The button press is likely to be grounded, pulled high, and re-grounded several times when the button is pressed before the switch settles in to the grounded state.

There are several common debounce algorithms.  You could read the state several times after the first change and only report "pressed" when several "0" in a row are reported after a very short delay.  There are more sophisticated algorithms if you Google around.

Good luck.

Comment: Could you tell me how i can implement a fix in my code?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a simple fix -- you need to incorporate the timing logic into your code and, ideally, you need to do the timing without blocking the rest of the application. I have some code I could share, which you could raid for ideas, if that's any help.

Comment: @kevin Boone can you please share it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Contact details are on my website, kevinboone.net.